# JPA Annotations for Multiple One-to-One Self-Referential Relations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-one

I'm trying to define the model for a task object that has a reference to the previous task, and a reference to the next task. This is how I have attempted to model those relationships in my `CompletableTask.java` class:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "previousTask", orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "next_task_id")
private CompletableTask nextTask;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "nextTask", orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "previous_task_id")
private CompletableTask previousTask;
```

However, when I boot up my application and let Hibernate create the necessary schema updates for this, I receive the following error log:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.my_package.CompletableTask.nextTask, referenced property unknown: com.my_package.CompletableTask.previousTask
```

I have been able to resolve this issue by simply removing the `mappedBy = "previousTask"` argument from the `nextTask`'s one-to-one annotation, but then no `previous_task_id` is present in the table that Hibernate generates, which I believe to be incorrect for my intended purposes.

Could someone please explain how I would go about modelling this? And in the case that it's impossible to achieve the desired schema that has references to both the next and previous tasks, what are my alternatives?

Comment: I would suggest that a task only stores one relation, e.g. the `nextTask`. If both relations are stored in every task, two rows have to hold the same relation (one task holds the `nextTask` relation, the other the `previousTask` relation, both referencing the other task). I am not sure if hibernate is able to handle data consistency if the relation is stored in multiple entities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mappedBy` denotes the attribute that "owns" the relationship in a bidirectional relationship. 
Therefore it does not make sense to have `mappedBy` on both side. 
Please remove one.

Comment: Yes, you're right. This is the structural reason why this was not allowed, but @Turing85 noted that alongside this, my design was flawed. For this application, I was essentially modelling a doubly-linked list, which contains redundant data that doesn't need to be persisted to know the full state. Thank you!